# How to change text and enable buttons from class?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a **TASK (in the other file)** - the file name is **(RestServices.cs)** that synced my users to my device.

```
public async Task FirstTimeSyncUser(string host, string database, string domain, string contact)
    {
        if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
        {
            var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>();
            var conn = db.GetConnection();

            string apifile = "first-time-sync-user-api.php";
            var current_datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            int count = 1;

            var uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://" + domain + "/TBSApi/" + apifile + "?Host=" + host + "&Database=" + database + "&ContactID=" + contact, string.Empty));

            try
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
                    {
                        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                        {
                            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
                        };

                        var dataresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserData>>(content, settings);
                        var datacount = dataresult.Count;

                        for (int i = 0; i < datacount; i++)
                        {
                            //syncStatus.Text = "Syncing user " + count + " out of " + datacount;

                            var item = dataresult[i];
                            var userid = item.UserID;
                            var usrpassword = item.UsrPassword;
                            var usertypeid = item.UserTypeID;
                            var userstatus = item.UserStatus;
                            var lastsync = DateTime.Parse(current_datetime);
                            var lastupdated = item.LastUpdated;
                            var deleted = item.Deleted;

                            var insertdata = new UserTable
                            {
                                UserID = userid,
                                UsrPassword = usrpassword,
                                ContactID = contact,
                                UserTypeID = usertypeid,
                                UserStatus = userstatus,
                                LastSync = lastsync,
                                LastUpdated = lastupdated,
                                Deleted = deleted
                            };

                            await conn.InsertOrReplaceAsync(insertdata);

                            count++;
                        }

                        var logType = "App Log";
                        var log = "Initialized first-time sync (<b>User</b>)  <br/>" + "App Version: <b>" + Constants.appversion + "</b><br/> Device ID: <b>" + Constants.deviceID + "</b>";
                        int logdeleted = 0;

                        await Save_Logs(contact, logType, log, database, logdeleted);

                        Preferences.Set("userchangeslastcheck", current_datetime, "private_prefs");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var retry = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("First-time User Sync Error", "Syncing failed. Status Code:\n\n" + response.StatusCode, "Yes", "No");

                    if (retry.Equals(true))
                    {
                        await FirstTimeSyncUser(host, database, domain, contact);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        First_Time_OnSyncFailed();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(ex);
                var retry = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("First-time User Sync Error", "Syncing failed.\n\n Error:\n\n" + ex.Message, "Yes", "No");

                if (retry.Equals(true))
                {
                    await FirstTimeSyncUser(host, database, domain, contact);
                }
                else
                {
                    First_Time_OnSyncFailed();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var retry = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("First-time User Sync Error", "Syncing failed. Please connect to the internet to sync your data. Do you want to retry?", "Yes", "No");

            if (retry.Equals(true))
            {
                await FirstTimeSyncUser(host, database, domain, contact);
            }
            else
            {
                First_Time_OnSyncFailed();
            }
        }
    }
```

I also have a label in my XAML (SyncPage.xaml).

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <ActivityIndicator x:Name="actindicator" HeightRequest="120" Color="#1abc9c" IsRunning="True"/>
                <Label StyleClass="lblSync" x:Name="syncStatus" Text="Getting data from server">
                    <Label.FontFamily>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                            <On Platform="Android" Value="HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt.otf#HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt"/>
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </Label.FontFamily>
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End">
                <Button Text="Continue" Clicked="btnContinue_Clicked" StyleClass="btn-login" x:Name="btnContinue" BorderRadius="6" IsVisible="False">
                    <Button.FontFamily>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                            <On Platform="Android" Value="HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt.otf#HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt"/>
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </Button.FontFamily>
                </Button>
                <Button Text="Continue" Clicked="btnBack_Clicked" StyleClass="btn-login" x:Name="btnBack" BorderRadius="6" IsVisible="False">
                    <Button.FontFamily>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                            <On Platform="Android" Value="HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt.otf#HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt"/>
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </Button.FontFamily>
                </Button>
            </StackLayout>
```

What I want to achieve is to my **syncStatus(This is the ID of the label)** to display the inserting process like this

> syncStatus.Text = "Syncing user " + count + " out of " + datacount;

And also change the button to visible or not. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `System.Action` for this.

Make whatever changes that you want to happen in a method which will be present in your SyncPage.xaml.cs

```
private void CallBack(string strVal) // you can add parameters to this method if you want data with this callback
{
  Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=>{
  // code you want to perform on callback(On main thread)
   });
}
```

Pass this as a parameter in your call to the method in `RestServices`

```
RestServices.FirstTimeSyncUser(host,database,domain,contact,Callback)
 {....}
```

And once all the things that you wanted to be done are done call it something like below,
the callback will be called last after all your conditions meet and you have completed what you want

```
public async Task FirstTimeSyncUser(string host, string database, string domain, string contact, Action<string> callback)

{ 
  //Your code
  callback("Syncing your data please wait");
}
```

Comment: so I will add CallBack() on Syncpage.xaml.cs then I will call the CallBack int the RestServices with the parameters in what I want to display

Comment: Yeah something like that!

Comment: Oh ok I will try it

Comment: I tried it and I am having a hard time figuring it out. I want to change the **syncStatus**'s text using FirstTimeSyncUser lets say I want to change sycnStatus into "Syncing your data please wait" using FirstTimeSyncUser how can I do that? Can you show me?

Comment: Done you may take a look

Comment: it is not working for me does callback in public async task small letter?

Comment: I am getting a Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: The callback method needs to run on UI thread Use `BeginInvokeOnMainThread`!!

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: It now working can you help me with my other problem? Here is my AnyDesk 782 114 930